# Writing a custom management command with a string argument

Tags: django, python-3.x

I know I can add arguments with the add_arguments method like this:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('--debug', action='store_true', dest='debug', default=False, help='print debug statements')
```

Is it possible to add an argument which has a String as type?
My use case is to add a path to a file.

Comment: `String as type` like this ah ?  --debug "your sting"

Comment: like this --f "/folder/file.txt"

Comment: I really don't want that string as type because user can select the file from tabs using normal.....

Comment: Is your question is " Add another argument to argparse?" or do you really want that `string as type` ?

Comment: I want to open files in my script so I need the path to the file

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FileType`

```
parser.add_argument("-f", type=argparse.FileType(), required=True)
```